# How to train YOLO-Tensor flow own dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying make an app which will detect traffic sign from video's frames.I am using yolo-tensor by following steps from https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow .

I need to know how can I train this model with my data-set of images of traffice signs?

Comment: Please post what progress you've made by following the instructions on the page. There's also some good information in the issues section. What have you tried so far?

Comment: My Steps: **1.** I cloned the code from github,I installed the darkflow successfully. **2.** I downloaded yolo-tiny.weight to test a sample image for this i uses the command `flow --imgdir sample_img/ --model cfg/yolo-tiny.cfg --load bin/yolo-tiny.weights --json` but it gave me the error that 'flow' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. **3.** I am trying to Train my own dataset but it was'nt clear to me that how do i make annotation?and the boundingbox you mentioned me earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Darkflow on Windows then you need to make some small adjustments to how you use Darkflow. If cloning the code and using straight from the repository then you need to place `python` in front of the commands given as it is a python file.

e.g. `python flow --imgdir sample_img/ --model cfg/yolo-tiny.cfg --load bin/yolo-tiny.weights --json`

If you are installing using pip globally (not a bad idea) and you still want to use the `flow` utility from any directory just make sure you take the flow file with you.

To train, use the commands listed on the github page here: https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow

If training on your own data you will need to take some extra steps as outlined here: https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow#training-on-your-own-dataset

Your annotations need to be in the popular PASCAL VOC format which are a set of xml files including file information and the bounding box data.

Point your flow command at your new dataset and annotations to train.

Comment: Thanks alot,Added python before flow worked for me.I tested it with some sample image it generated the json files for me.Now my own data is issue.

Comment: Please read through the link that I sent you before asking more questions. The information is in there.. It explains how to do transfer learning so that you you retrain the last 2 layers to generate new weights. The page explains it. You will need to make the annotations yourself to train a model.

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear.The section Train your own dataset i am following these steps to copy and make new cfg file with some changes of no of classes and filter.I need to know what structure show be of data,i am not familiar with annotation and how to make them with my images.At this point I just have some images of each type of sign.Please let me know how can i make annotation and bounding box data with images is there any tools or script here to generate it?

Comment: The data needs to be in the form of PASCAL VOC. It's a popular data format for annotations. It's xml format. You could try downloading some of VOC dataset to have a look at it what it looks like. If you look on the issues page of the darkflow project you will find lots of discussion about generating annotations. If you read through those discussions you'll find more info. You could use labelImg project on github to label your images or create your own tool. You will need to label manually though,

Comment: Thanks alot @JCooke I have made my dataset with annotation and trained it.But facing an issue when testing please help out,have a look https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/issues/345

Comment: I have replied to your issue on the repo. Your error was because you didn't fully follow the instructions and you didn't load the correct weights. We can continue the discussion over there.

Answer (score 0):

The best data for you to practice is PASCAL VOC dataset. There are 2 folders you need to prepare for the training. 1 folder with images and 1 folder with xml files(annotation folder), 1 image will need 1 xml file (have the same name) content all the basic informations (object name, object position, ...). after that you only need to choose 1 predefine .cfg file in cfg folder and run the command follow:

```
flow --model cfg/yolo-new.cfg --train --dataset "path/to/images/folder" --annotation "path/to/annotation/folder"
```

Read more the options supported by [darkflow](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow) to optimize more the training process.

Answer (score 0):

After spending too much time on how to train custom data set for object detection

Prerequisite :
1:training environment : a system with at least 4gb GPU or you can use AWS / GCP pre-configured cloud machine with cuda 9 installation
2: ubuntu 16.04 os 
3: images of the object you want to  detect. images size should not be too much large it will create out of memory issue in dataset  training
4: labelling tool many are available like LabelImg/ BBox-Label-Tool i used is also good one 
I tried python project dataset-generator also but result of labelling using dataset generator was not efficient in real time scenarios

My suggestion for training environment is to use AWS machine rather than spend time in local installation of cuda and cudnn even though you are able to install cuda locally but if you are not having GPU >= 4 gb you will not be able to train many times it will break due to out of memory issue

solutions to train data set :

1: train ssd_mobilenet_v2 data set using tensorflow object detection api
this training output can be use on both android , ios platform

2: use darknet to train data set which required pascal VOC data format of labelling , for that labelIMG can do the job of labelling very good
3: retrain that data weights which comes as output from darknet with  darkflow